# Lebesgue integral $\int 0d\mu=0?$ How to compute it?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f=0$ over the real line, $\mathbb R$, with Lebesgue measure $\mu$. I'm uncertain about how to compute the Lebesgue integral, $\int fd\mu=\int 0d\mu.$  Is it $0$?

In this case, $f=0$ is a simple function.  So by definition, $\int fd\mu=0\mu(\mathbb R)=0\cdot \infty.$  Do we simply define this to be zero for Lebesgue integral?

I thought about countable additivity of the measure, i.e. $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty E_n$, where $E_n\triangleq (-n-1,-n] \cup [n,n+1),$  and $\mu(E_n)=2.$  So $0\mu(\mathbb R)=0\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(E_n)=0\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2.$  But $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2$ is a divergent series, does the usual distributive law apply here?  I.e. can we say $0\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0\cdot 2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0=0?$

Even if so, it still boils down to a definition, isn't it?  I.e. Why should $0\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0\cdot 2?$  Unless we define $0\cdot \infty = 0.$  Or we make the distributive law hold in this case, and $0\cdot \infty = 0$ follows as a consequence.

Did I miss something?  Are there other ways to justify what $\int 0d\mu$ should be?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: In measure theory $0 \cdot \infty = 0$

Comment: Additionally, we usually define the lebesge integral as the improper Riemann integral over the function $f^*(x) = \mu(\{y\,|\,f(y)>x\})$; that is, the integral $\int_0^\infty dx\, f^*(x)$, yet $f^*(x)$ is identically zero, everywhere.